Se puede modificar el scrollLeft y scrollTop de un div?
estoy intentando hacer el efecto de que un div parezca que es un espacio de trabajo "infinito" donde el usuario ira generando un árbol genealógico,  el caso es que por defecto estoy creando un nodo principal a partir del cual irán saliendo otros nodos.
resulta que para que la pagina cargue en el centro de mi div que se llama .cont0 (en este caso mide 10000px x 10000px) no se como acceder a su propiedad scrollLeft y scrollTop para poder cambiar esos valores. En cambio si el overflow en lugar de provocarse en un div se provoca en la etiqueta  con window.scrollTo(centerX, centerY) si que puedo lograr centrar la pagina en el centro del contenedor pero si por ejemplo recojo el contenedor .cont0 en un div como en esta funcion no soy capaz de cambiarle el valor a los scrollTop y scrollLeft:
    // Obtiene el contenedor del árbol genealógico
    const zeroContainer = document.querySelector('.cont0');

    if (zeroContainer) {
       
        //Calcular la distancia del scroll del contenedor menos el tamaño de la pantalla dividido entre 2
        const centerX = (zeroContainer.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth) / 2;
        const centerY = (zeroContainer.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) / 2;

        //Ajustar el scroll para centrar el contenedor con el resultado de los cálculos
        zeroContainer.scrollLeft = centerX;
        zeroContainer.scrollTop = centerY;

    }
}```

PD: Es mi proyecto de final de ciclo, y la primera vez que escribo aquí, por favor no seáis muy duros!


Estás seguro de que estás intentando asignarle los valores scrollLeft y scrollTop a un elemento concreto?? Estás haciendo un querySelector sobre una CLASE, y puede haber múltiples elementos con una misma clase. Probaste a imprimir el valor de zeroContainer a ver qué es?? Por cierto, te recomiendo proveernos de un [mre], es decir, un trozo de código FUNCIONANDO que reproduzca tu problema. Somos programadores, no adivinos. Si no podemos ejecutar tu código no podemos ver dónde estás fallando.

una opcion es poner un addEventListener que detecte los cambios en el div (asignale un id para identificarlo), una vez hecho esto puedes edfinir el centro en cada instante que este cambie


let d = window.document.getElementById('id del elemento')
    d.addEventListener('change',()=>{
      //Calcular la distancia del scroll del contenedor menos el tamaño de la pantalla dividido entre 2
      const centerX = (zeroContainer.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth) / 2;
      const centerY = (zeroContainer.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) / 2;

      //Ajustar el scroll para centrar el contenedor con el resultado de los cálculos
      zeroContainer.scrollLeft = centerX;
      zeroContainer.scrollTop = centerY;
    })



s
